# How do I self reference a table in typeorm in a many-many relationship joined via JoinTable?

Tags: nestjs, relationship, entity-relationship, typeorm

I am a novice in using typeorm but do have an understanding of the concepts of relationships in typeorm. I am using nestjs with typeorm and have 2 tables, Products and Links which have a many-many relationship.

**link.entity.ts**

```
@Entity({ name: 'links' })
export class Link {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  code: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;

  @ManyToMany(() => Product)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'link_products',
    joinColumn: { name: 'link_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'product_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  product: Product[];

  ...
}
```

**product.entity.ts**

```
@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  image: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;
}
```

**link.controller.ts**

```
export class LinkController {
  constructor(
    private readonly linkService: LinkService,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Post('ambassador/links')
  async create(@Body('products') products: number[], @Req() request: Request) {
    const user = await this.authService.user(request);
    return this.linkService.create({
      code: Math.random().toString(36).substr(6),
      user,
      products: products.map((id) => ({ id })),
    });
  }

  @Get('checkout/links/:code')
  async link(@Param('code') code: string) {
    return await this.linkService.findOne({
      code,
      relations: ['user', 'product'],
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

In the link controller, I am creating a link for an ambassador with the body containing an array of product ids.
This would return a random code.
What I want is that when I hit the Get route copy pasting the code that I received, it should show up all the products that are associated with that link but I am instead getting a null array

*Example demonstration:*

1. Inserting products for a link

   POST: http://localhost:8000/api/ambassador/links

   body: {
   "products":[6,2]
   }

Output:

```
{
    "code": "e37dufa",
    "user": {
        "id": 11,
        "first_name": "ambassador",
        "last_name": "ambassador",
        "email": "ambassador@ambassador.com",
        "is_ambassador": true
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 6
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```

2. Getting the link:

   GET: http://localhost:8000/api/checkout/links/e37dufa

Output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": "e37dufa",
    "user": {
        "id": 11,
        "first_name": "ambassador",
        "last_name": "ambassador",
        "email": "ambassador@ambassador.com",
        "is_ambassador": true
    },
    "product": []
}
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind two way like shown below. Now you can access `link.products` or `product.links`.

#### Link.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => Product, product => product.links)
@JoinTable()
products: Product[]
```

#### Product.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => Link, link => link.products)
links: Link[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't really do anything. I am still getting the same empty output as before like I showed in the example. I am not very knowledgeable about JoinTable and the instructor wasn't very clear about JoinTable, I could be wrong but how I used JoinTable originally does the same thing I think as your solution.

Comment: I spotted my mistake, it was a typo @.@ ...instead of products, I should have used product in "this.linkService.create()" function.